# Dynamic Query building using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, performance

I Have search functionality in my application. In my search form consist of many options , few example are

1. I have totally 6 select boxes  and two text boxes in my search form.

Based on the user selection . I have to build the CAML jquery Dynamically  .

My point here is I can create the CAML Query

Following are the steps , I have followed to create CAML Query ;

1. Reading selected and typed values in the form by using   #id.val() for each html element.
2. Then apply the  IF condition, to get to know what are all the options are selected in the form.
3. Then send the string (framed query)  .

I want to know, if there any way in jQuery  to read only selected values in a fast and generic way.  Any mechanism is available for building query in Jquery?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand fully your question. I just hope to misunderstand the part where you seem to want to build a MySQL query client side... This would be a major security hole. And instead of all this text, you'd have better to provide a concrete example of what you are looking for

Comment: Hi Wolff, I never excute MYSQL in Jquery layer. Based on user selection . I build the Mysql Query as a string. and post the query for execution by using Jquery AjAx method.

Comment: Well, what will happen if user send then a `DROP DATABASE xxx;` ??? I guess you set some privileges but anyway, this is for sure a NO GO...

Comment: Though the use typed DROP DATABASE XXXX; We have privilege in database.  Is there any way to read all the 6 select box selected values at a time? Instead of writing 6 select box ID and read each value as a separate

Comment: Anyway your user could still make some SQL injections, so you are just asking for trouble. Regarding your other question, just set specific class to all the SELET elements (or use 'select' as selector) and map the values. Or serialize it or whatever. I'd suggest you to read some basic tutos. This is just too broad question

Comment: Oh My bad !!!!!. We are going to use CAML Query builder NOT MYSQL. Sorry to making trouble.  Thanks Wolff. Let me try with your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but you really shouldn't construct the SQL query client-side.  Send the parameters of the form to the server and build the query there.

> I want to know, if there any way in jQuery to read only selected values in a fast and generic way. Any mechanism is available for building query in Jquery?

To answer this, I made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/connerbryan/45rnc/4/

`$("option:selected")` grabs all the selections, then by looping through and calling `.parent()` we can get the field name.

```
var selected = $('#myform option:selected');

selected.each(function(index, element) {
    var owner = $(element).parent().get(0);
    var field = owner.name;
    var value = element.value;
});
```

Again, I really don't recommend this.  The SQL could easily be modified by an unscrupulous user.

Comment: Hi Conner Bryan.. Yeah I understand my mistake. I have wrongly framed the question. My Ultimate read the values in a quicker way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="myselect">
<option value="1">Mr</option>
<option value="2">Mrs</option>
<option value="3">Ms</option>
<option value="4">Dr</option>
<option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>
```

use to get text $( "#myselect option:selected" ).text(); or $( "#myselect option:selected" ).val();

Comment: Hi,  In a select box user will select only one option at a time. multiselect option is disable. All i want to know is, I have 6 select boxes , Is there any way to read all the 6 select box selected values at a time.

Comment: Use a same class in all element and use each function to get all values.